# Laravel 5.4: Laravel mix.js - compile js files from multiple paths and output in different files?

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-5.4

I'm new to Laravel mix, struggling to understand how the entry point can be changed.

My question is ... **Is it possible to change the entry point of Laravel.mix.js, so that we can get multiple files from multiple paths, and output them accordingly?**

To clarify the point, here are what I'd like to achieve...

1.compile many files from `resources/assets/js/lib` and output the compiled `lib.js` into `public/js`.

2.compile many files from `resources/assets/js/others` and output the compiled `others.js` into `public/js`.

By default, we see the following line in `webpack.mix.js`.

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

However, when I change it into the following line, this results in an error.

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/lib/*.js', 'public/js/lib.js');
```

Error message -

> This dependency was not found:
>
> - /ROOT/resources/assets/js/lib/* .js in multi ./resources/assets/js/lib/*.js
>
> To install it, you can run: npm install --save /ROOT/resources/assets/js/lib/ *.js

It seems like it's not allowed to change the entry point (i.e. `resources/assets/js/app.js`).

Interestingly, the following line combines all the js files properly.

```
mix.scripts('resources/assets/js/lib/*.js', 'public/js/lib.js');
```

However, this simply combines and update files, not detect syntax errors.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this below...

```
mix.combine(['resources/assets/js/lib/*'], 'public/js/lib.js');
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, this just combines files without catching a syntax error. I'll add more explanation above in case other there are other programmers who have the same issue.